# Could not make bootstrap-table to load data using using Java script

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am newbie trying to learn bootstrap-table, and have been struggling for a while with basic data load using javascript. Code below seems to work but returns the result "No matching records found".

Will appreciate guidance on what I am doing wrong.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, Bootstrap Table!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table" data-toggle="table" ></table>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var data = '[{"id": 0,"name": "Item 0","price": "$0"}, {"id": 1,"name": "Item 1","price": "$1"},{"id": 2,"name": "Item 2","price": "$2"}]';
   data_json=JSON.parse(data);
   $('#table').bootstrapTable('load',data_json);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your `$('#table').bootstrapTable()` to the following:

```
<script>
    var data = '[{"id": 0,"name": "Item 0","price": "$0"}, {"id": 1,"name": "Item 1","price": "$1"},{"id": 2,"name": "Item 2","price": "$2"}]';
    data_json=JSON.parse(data);
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data_json
    });
</script>
```

Okay, you will then now see a blank page (without `No matchign records`). Change the `<table>` tag in your HTML to the following:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" >
  <thead>
    <th>Item ID</th>
    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
    <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

`<thead>` must be present so that `bootstrap-table` knows which to display.

Comment: Your suggestion worked great ! Thank you very much. I added: <th data-field="id">Item ID</th> to properly display "id" column